# Antiderivative of $\operatorname{sech^{2n}(n-m)}$?

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-functions

I want to find the indefinite integral of $\operatorname{sech^{2n}(n-m)}$ where $m$ is a constant and the function's argument is $n$. I know that

$$\operatorname{sech(n-m)}=\frac{1}{\operatorname{cosh(n)}\operatorname{cosh(m)}-\operatorname{sinh(n)}\operatorname{sinh(m)}}$$

and therefore

$$\operatorname{sech^{2n}(n-m)}\mathrm dn=\frac{1}{\bigl(\operatorname{cosh(n)}\operatorname{cosh(m)}-\operatorname{sinh(n)}\operatorname{sinh(m)}\bigr)^{2n}}$$

Also that

$$\operatorname{\int {sech^{2}(n)}}\mathrm dn=\operatorname{tanh(n)}+C$$

but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @Taladris Neither, $\int \text{sech}^{2n}(n - m) \ \text{d}n$.

Comment: Do you mean $\operatorname{\int {sech^{2}x}}\mathrm dx=\operatorname{tanh(n)}+C?$  $\operatorname{\int {sech^{2}(n)}}\mathrm dx=x \operatorname{sech}^2{n}+C$

Comment: Apologies, I got my arguments muddled - question amended.

Comment: So the integration variable is in the exponent? I wouldn't hold out much hope, then.

Comment: Hi @J.G. - thank you (and I hope someone proves you wrong!), but is it possible to explain why?

Comment: Did you try a u sub for n-m or something similar?

Comment: Hi @Axion004, I'm afraid I don't know what you mean...?

Comment: Nevermind, I don't think the u sub will work as https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sech(n-m)%5E(2n)+dn. There could be a trick (unknown to me) that you could use to solve this integral.

Comment: One thing you must learn to accept is that almost all elementary functions (functions expressible in terms of addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and exponentiation - which includes trig functions courtesy of $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$) have anti-derivatives that are not elementary, and therefore must be expressed in other means. Taylor series are probably your best bet here.